# Older OS versions and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm a noob with Xamarin.Forms, but trying to get going with it. My first project involves updating and unifying some existing apps. The iOS version of the app targets iOS 6.0, and the Android version requires 2.3.3 or newer.

What are the oldest versions of iOS and Android respectively that I will be able to target if I want to use Xamarin.Forms and achieve a common UI implementation?

Comment: Obviously I don't know what kind of a niche is your app targeting but you may want to take into consideration market share of each version. Only 2% use a version older than iOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/  For Android things are a bit worse with 6.8% using Gingerbread (2.3.3) or older  https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone

Answer (score 1):

You need to target iOS 6.1 and Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15) or higher to use Xamarin.Forms

You can find the requirements here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Target_Platforms